# Create new formula field that returns type checkbox in SFDC

Tags: formula-field

I want to create a formula field that returns type checkbox on the Opportunity object. The 3 Fields are

Demo Completed = If this is blank the demo has not been completed
Demo Date = The date the demo is scheduled.

So want I want to create is to show me any demos that have yet to complete where the current date is > Demo Date meaning the demo did not complete

Something like:

If (demo Complete = "", demo date < Today(), ""), but im getting an error saying "Incorrect parameter type for operator '='. Expected DateTime, received Text"

Answer (score 0):

You could try using IsBlank instead of = ''.

```
IF(ISBLANK(Demo_Completed__c) && Demo_Date__c < TODAY(), true, false)
```

Comment: Close, but I think the `&&` needs to be an `||` based on OP's explanation, and the result being false if the "Demo Completed" field is not blank doesn't make much sense. Also, `IF(<condition>, true, false)` can be simplified (you only need the condition).

Comment: If( ISBLANK( Demo_Completed__c )|| Demo_Date__c < TODAY(),TRUE,FALSE)

I just put this and i get the error "Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '<'. Expected DateTime, received Date" thoughts?

Comment: @RK5123 you can  change the Today() for a NOW() and this would fix that issue. Today returns just the date, and NOW() the date/time.

Answer (score 0):

In formulas (and also in programming in general), you need to make sure that the data types you're using are compatible.

e.g. the first parameter for the `IF()` function expects a *boolean* (a true/false)
so `IF(5 > 4, ...)` is correct because the result of `5 > 4` is *boolean*
and `IF("like and subscribe", ...)` is incorrect because `"like and subscribe"` is *a string*, and string is not compatible with boolean
even something like `IF("true", ...)` is still incorrect, because the string `"true"` is *not the same thing as the boolean literal `true`*

Based on your error message, `Demo_Completion_Date__c` is a *Datetime*
Datetime and String are *not compatible*, so `Demo_Completion_Date__c = ""` is a syntax error (both sides of equality, inequality, greater than, less than, etc... need to be of compatible types)

If you want to see if a Datetime is empty or not, you want to use the `ISBLANK()` function.

Also, Since your formula type is `checkbox` (i.e. a boolean value), your formula needs to return a boolean value.
`IF(<condition>, true, false)` can *always* be simplified to just `<condition>`, so the formula you're looking for here would be

```
/* OR() results in true if at least one condition is true */
OR(
    NOT(ISBLANK(Demo_Completion_Date__c)),
    /* TODAY() gives you a Date, NOW() gives you a Datetime */
    Demo_Date__c < NOW()
)
```